# Batch script for unattended install of a software

Tags: installation, microsoft-office, batch, automation

I've got a few programs i need to install every time i reinstall a computer

- office 2003 Pro
- office 2007 compatibility pack
- Adobe acrobat
- Adobe flash

but i hate to do this every time on every computer 
ive already made a batch script when i boot xp the first time after reinstall like

```
@echo off
"I:\installs\adobe reader\setup.exe"
pause
"I:\installs\office 2003\setup.exe"
pause
"I:\installs\office compatibilitiy\setup.exe"
```

but it doesnt install automatically, 
is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should google "silent install name_of_software" or "unattended name_of_software"

or looking directly there:

http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php

http://www.msfn.org/board/forum/80-application-installs/

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good article here on the subject: [script](http://www.fasttrackscript.com/installations)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to take an image of the disk and then apply that when you re-install. You'll want software that can clone a disk [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_cloning). There are several programs out there, I haven't used any recently so I can't recommend one.

It does mean you have to do one last manual install of everything, but after that it should be a simple matter of copying the cloned disk back onto your hard drive.

Comment: How about interactive input like dreaded serial numbers etc? That breaks the automation via batch files only. Something like AutoIt could probably be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Office 2003 uses MST transform files to automate the installation process. They can be a bit tricky to setup, but once you haver your MST file you can use it to do an [unattended installation of Office 2003](http://unattended.msfn.org/unattended.xp/view/web/50/)

Answer (score 0):

well, you could write a script with  a program like  autoit  or autohotkeys

I suppose the jist can be to launch the installation, and then send tab and space, and so on, to get through the installation the way you want it.